# Ubuntu login screen instead of suspending

Tags: suspend, login-screen, 21.10

after updating to ubuntu 21 when I try to suspend, the screen will only turn black for a while and then the login screen apears. If I press suspend again, the screen turns black again and I'm stuck in this weird state, where there's nothing but a blinking curser on the screen! Please help, I want to sleep...

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post hardware specifications, especially graphics. Also describe how you updated to "Ubuntu 21". BTW, there's no Ubuntu 21. Ubuntu desktop is always YY.MM. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have the proper video card driver:
Check what video card you have in your system

```
sudo lshw -C display
```

If you use GUI, try this:
Open "Software Updater"->Settings->Additional Drivers and wait for it to find the available dirvers.
You should see your video board name on top and few options below. Select the one named: "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-...some_version_here... (proprietary,tested)".
Then "Apply changes".
It will ask for root password! You may avoid this by launching Software Updater like this:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/update-manager
```

Reboot.

Comment: Wow, you're amazing that worked! How do you guys do that?